# yii bootstrap calendar template change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have installed the yii bootstrap calendar from following URL

https://github.com/femike/yii-bootstrap-calendar/tree/master/lib/bootstrap-calendar

It is displaying correctly for me.

I want to change the calendar template.

The template files are in "assets/tmpls" folder. If i change the html file in the tmpls folder, it is not changed.

I couldn't know where i changed the template?

Please give me suitable answer please.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the layout by changing the css file in this folder:

```
yii-bootstrap-calendar/blob/master/lib/bootstrap-calendar/assets/css/calendar.css
```